# SQL not splitting sec_to_time sum

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to split the Sum on each query by campaign_id.

For an example if `agent1` went into `campaign_id`: 505 and went into Admin for 1 hour. And `Agent1` also wen't into `campaign_id`: for 2 hours.

This needs to split, but it's showing `Campaign_id`: 3 hours.

**Code**

```
    set @fromDate = '2018-06-29 00:00:01';
    set @ToDate = '2018-06-29 23:59:59';

    SELECT full_name,
    log.user,
    log.campaign_id,
    count(log.Status) as calls (sec_to_time(sum(pause_sec)+sum(wait_sec)+sum(talk_sec)+sum(dispo_sec)+sum(dead_sec))) as AgentTime,
    (sec_to_time(sum(log.wait_sec))) as Wait,
    (sec_to_time(sum(log.talk_sec))) as Talk,
    (sec_to_time(sum(log.dispo_sec))) as Dispo,
    (sec_to_time(sum(log.dead_sec))) as Dead,
    (sec_to_time(sum(log.pause_sec))) as Pause, 
    Adminlog.Admin,
    BreakLog.Break,
    BUZZLog.BUZZ,
    ITLog.IT,
    LaggedLog.Lagged,

FROM Table1 as log
left join table2 as users
on log.user = users.user

left join (SELECT 
        user,
        campaign_id,
        (sec_to_time(sum(pause_sec))) as Admin
        from Table1 
        where (sub_status='Admin')
        and (event_time > @fromDate and event_time < @toDate)
        group by user) as Adminlog
    on log.user = Adminlog.user

left join (SELECT
        user,
        campaign_id,
        (sec_to_time(sum(pause_sec))) as Break
        from Table1 
        where (sub_status='Break')
        and (event_time > @fromDate and event_time < @toDate)
        group by user) as BreakLog
    on log.user = BreakLog.user

left join (SELECT
        user,
        campaign_id,
        (sec_to_time(sum(pause_sec))) as BUZZ
        from Table1 
        where (sub_status='BUZZ')
        and (event_time > @fromDate and event_time < @toDate)
        group by user) as BUZZLog
    on log.user = BUZZLog.user

left join (SELECT
        user,
        campaign_id,
        (sec_to_time(sum(pause_sec))) as IT
        from Table1 
        where (sub_status='IT')
        and (event_time > @fromDate and event_time < @toDate)
        group by user) as ITLog
    on log.user = ITLog.user

left join (SELECT
        user,
        campaign_id,
        (sec_to_time(sum(pause_sec))) as Lagged
        from Table1 
        where (sub_status='Lagged')
        and (event_time > @fromDate and event_time < @toDate)
        group by user) as LaggedLog
    on log.user = LaggedLog.user

where (log.event_time > @fromDate and event_time < @toDate)

group by campaign_id, user
```

**Result**

```
Full_name  User  Campaign_id  Calls  AgentTime ..... Admin
Agent1     101      505         2    01:01:23       01:54:57
Agent1     101      506         4    05:12:20       01:54:57
Agent1     101      507         22   00:21:36       01:54:57
```

In this example I would need the "Admin" to show the Admin time for that campaign.

Comment: What type of SQL?

Comment: Hi Shawn, MYSQL. Thanks

Comment: I feel like there are some words missing from our "for example", but examining the query my first instinct is that you should probably be grouping your subqueries by `user` and `campaign_id` if you expect to have anything meaningfully related to the capaign_id in your results.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment Uueerdo. Not sure why my example has come out like that.. I tried the user, Camapign_id on the sub queries and still got the same :(